# Подскажите плагин и/или скрипт для Callback виджета и/или вызова всплывающего окна по нажатию "своей" кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, адаптивная-верстка, wordpress-плагины

Установлены CF 7 и Wpforms, но из коробки вроде нельзя привязать вызов формы по нажатию на "свой" button (гайды устарели, а в JS совсем плох), чтобы, к примеру, запросить у посетителя номер телефона (желательно с флагом страны и набранным +7) и email-ом. Подойдет и сторонний сервис. Куда именно будут попадать получаемые данные сейчас не важно (базу или почту), лишь бы работало)

С уважением.

Comment: Вы можете скачать плагин для создания popup окон а-ля попап мейкер, создать в нем попап, в качестве триггера поставить нажатие на элемент с id вашей кнопки, а в качестве содержимого указать шорткод от CF7

Comment: спасибо родной.

Answer (score 1):

Вы также можете поставить Elementor и использовать его формы и обработчики